# Não consigo sair da aplicação mobile

Tags: android, apache-cordova

Estou com seguinte problema com o phonegap, ao tentar executar o seguinte instrução:

```js
navigator.app.exitApp();
```

O android apenas deixa em segundo plano a aplicação, a tela some mais ainda fica em segundo plano, ou seja quando eu clico no botão para mostrar os aplicativos abertos ele ainda esta lá

Alguém pode me ajudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jacob, isso acontece pois você não pode "fechar" uma aplicação, somente o sistema Android que pode decidir quando uma aplicação sairá do stack, o fato de o aplicativo ficar na aba de aplicativos recentes, não significa que ele está rodando em segundo plano.

Não conheço bem como funciona o Phonegap, porém, ele com certeza roda dentro de uma Activity Android, então aconselho dar uma olhada no [Ciclo de vida de uma Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) para entender melhor como o Android gerencia sua aplicação.

Comment: Valeu Lucas vou ver esse link

Comment: O importante é você sempre ter em mente que você não controla o ciclo de vida da aplicação, então, quando a mesma deixar de ser visível o sistema pode destruí-la a qualquer momento (caso o sistema necessite de recursos para o aplicativo em primeiro plano), então se você precisar fazer algo antes da aplicação fechar, utilize os métodos `onStop` ou `onDestroy`